# How to protect enum assignment

Tags: c, testing, enums, compile-time, compile-time-constant

I want to prevent invalid value enum assignment. I know if i even assign value that is not in enum it will work. Example:

```
enum example_enum
{
    ENUM_VAL0,
    ENUM_VAL1,
    ENUM_VAL2,
    ENUM_VAL3
};

void example_function(void)
{
  enum example_enum the_enum = ENUM_VAL3; // correct
  the_enum = 41; // will work
  the_enum = 0xBADA55; // also will work
  bar(the_enum); // this function assumes that input parameter is correct
}
```

Is there easy, efficient way to check if assignment to enum is correct? I could test value by function

```
void foo(enum example_enum the_enum)
{
  if (!is_enum(the_enum))
    return;

  // do something with valid enum
}
```

I could resolve this in following way:

```
static int e_values[] = { ENUM_VAL0, ENUM_VAL1, ENUM_VAL2, ENUM_VAL3 };
int is_enum(int input)
{
  for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
    if (e_values[i] == input)
      return 1;
  return 0;
}
```

For me, my solution is inefficient, how can i write this if i have more enums and more values in enums?

Comment: Compiler warnings perhaps?

Comment: Use an assertion. In C `enum`s are actually `int`. C is not C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the `enum` is continuous one can do something like this:

```
static int e_values[] = { ENUM_VAL0, ENUM_VAL1, ENUM_VAL2, ENUM_VAL3, ENUM_VAL_COUNT };

int is_enum(int input) { return 0 <= input && input < ENUM_VAL_COUNT; }
```

Another alternative is to not validate the enum value beforehand, but error out once the code detects an invalid value:

```
switch(input) {
    case ENUM_VAL0: ... break;
    case ENUM_VAL1: ... break;
    ...
    default:
        assert(0 && "broken enum"); 
        break;
}
```

But there is no way to enforce that the `enum` value doesn't go out of the range at all in C. The best you can do if you want to secure the `enum` against fiddling is to hide the value away in a `struct` and then have functions to manipulate the `struct`. The function and `struct` implementation can be hidden away from the user via a forward declaration in the `.h` file and the implementation in the `.c` file:

```
struct example_t {
     enum example_enum value;
}

void example_set_val0(example_t* v) { v->value = ENUM_VAL0; }
```

Comment: Well, i think using `return 0 <= input && input < ENUM_VAL_COUNT;` is the best solution but only for continuous enums. Unfortunately i have usb_class enum and it is jagged. I have to put it into struct

Answer (score 1):

There is no way of warning about assigning integers that fit into the enum.

Enumerators in C are synonyms for integer types. Assuming the type chosen for `enum example_enum` is int, then your code is identical to:

```
void example_function(void)
{
  int the_enum = ENUM_VAL3; // correct
  the_enum = 12345; // will work
  bar(the_enum); // this function assumes that input parameter is correct
}

void foo(int the_enum)
{
  if (!is_enum(the_enum))
    return;
  // do something with valid enum
}
```

You could use structures, but even that can be circumvented:

```
struct example_enum_struct e = { 12345 };
e.value = 23456;
```

Basically if you want to restrict a type to specific values, you will need to perform checks.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is interested in this topic, here I have some solution which works.

typed_enums.h

```
#ifndef TYPED_ENUMS_H
#define TYPED_ENUMS_H

#define TYPED_ENUM(name_) \
    typedef struct { int v; } name_

#define TYPED_ENUM_VALUE(name_, value_)       (name_) { value_ }
#define GET_TYPED_ENUM_VALUE(en_)             (en_.v)
#define TYPED_ENUM_EQ(a_, b_)                 (GET_TYPED_ENUM_VALUE(a_) == GET_TYPED_ENUM_VALUE(b_))

#endif
```

usb_class.h

```
#ifndef USB_CLASS_H
#define USB_CLASS_H

#include "typed_enums.h"

TYPED_ENUM(UsbClass);

#define USB_CLASS_BILLBOARD                     TYPED_ENUM_VALUE(UsbClass, 0x11)
#define USB_CLASS_TYPE_C_BRIDGE                 TYPED_ENUM_VALUE(UsbClass, 0x12)
#define USB_CLASS_DIAGNOSTIC_DEVICE             TYPED_ENUM_VALUE(UsbClass, 0xDC)
#define USB_CLASS_WIRELESS_CONTROLLER           TYPED_ENUM_VALUE(UsbClass, 0xE0)

#endif
```

usb_class_example.c

```
#include "typed_enums.h"
#include "usb_class.h"

#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    UsbClass usbClass = USB_CLASS_WIRELESS_CONTROLLER;
    usbClass = 12345; // tadam!!!! throws error
    usbClass = USB_CLASS_VIDEO;
    if (TYPED_ENUM_EQ(usbClass, USB_CLASS_VIDEO)) {
        printf("usbClass = USB_CLASS_VIDEO\n");
    }

    printf("usb class value: %02X\n", GET_TYPED_ENUM_VALUE(usbClass));

    return 0;
}
```

Pros:

- enum value assignment works like struct assignment
- enum for pointers also works
- enum value can't be changed

Cons:

- can't be used in switch
- can't be directly compared
- can't directly return enum number value

Note: sorry for abusing preprocessor here