# Risks of adding uint to enum in function call

Tags: c, function, enums

I have a function that returns a float number:

```
float function(enum value)
```

I then have an enum

```
typedef enum
{
    a = 0,
    b,
    c
} myenum;
```

I want to do the following:

```
function(a+1);
```

And I wonder if there are any risks **other than the risk of unexpected behaviour if the enum changes**. My question might seem dumb but I have to make sure that there are no risks of what I'm doing.

Please don't ask questions on why it's done like this. Because I don't know. I just need to know if it's safe or not.

Comment: You have your answers, the code shown doesn't have any problems, still, if you don't know *why* you are doing something, that's often asking for trouble... (I don't want to know why, just saying *you* really *should* know)

Comment: You could steal this trick for [creating type-safe enums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43043246/how-to-create-type-safe-enums).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is safe. Moreover, the standard guarantees that `a+1` is `b` and `a+2` is `c` in the scenario that you describe:

> **C99 standard, section 6.7.2.2, part 3:** If the first enumerator has no `=`, the value of its enumeration constant is `0`. Each subsequent enumerator with no `=` defines its enumeration constant as the value of the constant expression obtained by adding `1` to the value of the previous enumeration constant.

Answer (score 1):

It's safe. As you seem to recognise yourself, it's really working against the way enums are intended to work, which is as arbitrary labels. However sometimes you want ordering such that a < b < c. If a = 0 and b = 1 and c = 2 in some firm sense, then you don't want an enum, however, you want a variable of type int.