# Assign values to enum in C

Tags: c

Is it legal to assign an int to an enum type as shown in c.color = 1?
I ran this code and it does seem to set c.color to BLUE as BYE is printed, but I wanted to understand if this actually sets the enum correctly.

```
typedef enum {
   GREEN = 0,
   BLUE
}COLOR;

typedef struct{
    COLOR color;
}COLORS;

int main()
{
    COLORS c;
    c.color = 1;
    if(c.color == BLUE)
    {
       printf("BYE");
    }
}
```

Comment: The short answer is 'Yes'. The `enum`, in addition to being an *integer type*, creates *global constants* that can, in return, be used to set the enum to any one of the values using the convenient constant as opposed to using a *magic number*, e.g. `enum direction { NORTH, WEST, SOUTH, EAST }; direction = SOUTH; switch direction { case NORTH: /* do suff */ break; case WEST: /* do stuff */ break; ...` You can use an `enum` for the purpose of declaring global constants independent of whether you use the `enum` later in your code, e.g. `enum { MAXC = 128, MAXN = 512 };`

Comment: Related topic: [How to create type safe enums?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43043246/how-to-create-type-safe-enums).

Answer (score 8):

An `enum` is considered an integer type.  So you can assign an integer to a variable with an `enum` type.

From section 6.2.5 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> *16* An
>   *enumeration* comprises  a  set  of  named  integer  constant  values.   Each  distinct enumeration constitutes a different
>   *enumerated type* .
>
> *17* The  type char ,  the  signed  and  unsigned  integer  types,  **and  the  enumerated  types  are collectively called integer types** .
>   The integer and real floating types are collectively called real types
>   .

Answer (score 3):

### Short Answer

Yes - it is "legal". The underlying type of an enum is an int.

However - consider avoiding the use of "Magic Numbers". See below.

---

### Cast the value (if you must use the number)

You can cast the int if you want to use the number while ensuring correct typing.  e.g.

```
c.color = (COLOR)1;
```

---

### Don't use Magic Numbers

While you **can** set an enum the way described in the question, the preference is to use the enum literal "BLUE" rather than the enum value "1".

Using a specific number in the code like this is called a "Magic Number", and makes the code harder to understand and maintain. It is "magic" because you can't determine what "1" means without looking it up, while you intuitively know what "BLUE" represents.

Someone coming back to the code later (including yourself months or years from now) will immediately understand what "BLUE" means, but will likely need to look up what "1" represents.

It might seem simple and intuitive with a small code sample like this, but once you have many files and layers to your code, writing readable, easily understandable code becomes very important.

Answer (score 2):

From the [CPP Reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/enum) website,

> Each enumerated type is compatible with one of: char, a signed integer
>   type, or an unsigned integer type. It is implementation-defined which
>   type is compatible with any given enumerated type, but whatever it is,
>   it must be capable of representing all enumerator values of that
>   enumeration.

You should be fine assigning an enum an integer value.

Answer (score 0):

According to C99 standard, enumerated types are considered integer types:

> The type `char`, the signed and unsigned integer types, and the enumerated types are collectively called *integer types*.

The standard allows assignments of integers to variables of enumerated types, but says that a compiler may issue a warning when this happens:

> An implementation may generate warnings in many situations, none of which are specified as part of this International Standard. The following are a few of the more common situations.
>
> ...
>
> [When] a value is given to an object of an enumerated type other than by assignment of an enumeration constant that is a member of that type, or an enumeration object that has the same type, or the value of a function that returns the same enumerated type (6.7.2.2).