# Using enum members with enum name in C

Tags: c, enums

I have defined the following enum:

```
typedef enum {
    F105 = 0x00,
    F164 = 0x10,
    F193 = 0x20,
    F226 = 0x30,
    F227 = 0x40
}BOARD_TYPE;
```

To make the code readable, I would like to use the enum name when using one of its members.  Like this:

```
void do_work(uint8_t board_type) {
    if (board_type == BOARD_TYPE.F164) {
        // Do stuff...
    }
}
```

Now, this doesn't compile.  I get an error message "Expected expression before 'BOARD_TYPE'".

So what would be the proper way of using a enum member while also referring to the enum name to increase code readability?

Comment: If it is just for readability you could include the enum name when declaring it's values, like `typedef enum { BOARD_TYPE_F105 = 0x00 } BOARD_TYPE`.

Comment: @LethalProgrammer you surely mean `board_type = F164`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`enum` is a list of values, an "enumeration". It is not a struct/container class with members.

Now what you *should* do for clarity is to only compare enumeration constants of a given type with variables of the same type. Not against `uint8_t` as in your example.

This is pretty much self-documenting code:

```
void do_work (BOARD_TYPE board_type) {
    if (board_type == F164) {
        // Do stuff...
    }
}
```

Good compilers can be configured to give warnings when comparing enums against wrong types. Otherwise you can also create [type safe enums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43043246/how-to-create-type-safe-enums) with some tricks.

You can also prefix all enum constants to indicate what type they belong to - this is common practice:

```
typedef enum {
    BOARD_F105 = 0x00,
    BOARD_F164 = 0x10,
    BOARD_F193 = 0x20,
    BOARD_F226 = 0x30,
    BOARD_F227 = 0x40
}BOARD_TYPE;
```

Comment: Ah, I like it.  Thanks for the input. :-)

Answer (score 3):

enum is not a structure and the member names are just names of the corresponding constants so you cant access enums elements via `.`

Change

```
BOARD_TYPE.F164
```

to

```
F164
```

enum constants are of type `int` so `board_type` will expand to `int`.

---

For better readability

```
typedef enum {
    BOARD_F105 = 0x00,
    BOARD_F164 = 0x10,
    BOARD_F193 = 0x20,
    BOARD_F226 = 0x30,
    BOARD_F227 = 0x40
}BOARD_TYPE;
```

---

Its always better to pass an enum type like

```
// Function definition
void do_work(BOARD_TYPE board_type) {
    if (board_type == BOARD_F164) {
        // Do stuff...
    }
}

// Calling
do_work(BOARD_F164);
```

Comment: Yes, obviously.  But then when reading the code later I lose the knowledge that F164 is a member of the enum "BOARD_TYPE".

Comment: So use it in name of constans ? `BOARD_F164`

Comment: Yes, that's possible.  But I would still like to indentify in the code which enum the value is defined in.  @Lundin had a good approach on this.  But thank you for your input.

Comment: @Oystein Isnt that the case with other types also? How do you remember what is type of your variables while reading code? Also F164 is "not  a member of enum"

Comment: @Vagish You're right - my terminology is a bit off.  "Value" would be a better word.  I guess you don't normally remember the type of the variable.  I just wanted a reference to the enum name, to make it more clear that the value "F164" was not just a defined value but a value in an enum.  But using the enum name as the variable type in the function arguments is a good approach, I think.

Answer (score 1):

`enum`s in C aren't classes like they are in Java. In general, you can't qualify the name of an `enum` with its type. That's why this fails:

```
typedef enum {
  F227 = 0x40 } BOARD_TYPE;

typedef enum {
  F227 = 0x40 } BOARD_TYPE2;
```

It's a little ugly, but I think the only way to get around this problem is to use the type in the name:

```
typedef enum {
  BOARD_TYPE_F227 = 0x40 } BOARD_TYPE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the enumeration value. Additionally you can use the enum-type as function parameter.

```
void do_work(BOARD_TYPE board_type) {
    if (board_type == F164) {
        // Do stuff...
    }
}
```

Comment: As I understand it, this isn't a question about validity, but about readability. There's no _need_ to qualify the enum name with its type, but on occasions it would be nice to be able to do so, to make the code more expressive. I don't think this can be done in C.

Comment: True, but there is no explizit type for enums, so you can get an implizit type cast warning (depends on compiler an warning level settings). Or you do  if ((BOARD_TYPE)board_type == F164).