# "error: ‘_Generic’ specifies two compatible types" but not on some compilers

Tags: c, generics, compiler-errors, macros, c11

I have a (complex) code that works on IAR compiler.
I took part of that code to make a snippet to improve it.
But while moving a part of this code on an online compiler, it would not compile.

The "error: ‘_Generic’ specifies two compatible types"

Because I was using _Generic as this example:

```
#define  GET_TYPE_(data) _Generic((&data)+0, \
           _Bool * : TYPE_BOOL_, \
           uint8_t* : TYPE_U8_, \
           uint16_t* : TYPE_U16_, \
           uint32_t* : TYPE_U32_, \
           someEnum1_e* : TYPE_BOOL_, \
           someEnum2_e* : TYPE_SPECIAL_A, \
           someEnum3_e* : TYPE_SPECIAL_B, \
           default: TYPE_DEFAULT_ )
```

With TYPE_XXX being a #define, then I can call

```
switch(GET_TYPE_(myVariable))
{ 
case TYPE_XXXX: do_something(); break;
...
}
```

But when I moved it with on the online compiler (online gdb) with gcc,
i got the error:

```
error: ‘_Generic’ specifies two compatible types
   someEnum1_e* : TYPE_BOOL_, \
error: ‘_Generic’ specifies two compatible types
   someEnum2_e* : TYPE_SPECIAL_A, \
error: ‘_Generic’ specifies two compatible types
   someEnum3_e* : TYPE_SPECIAL_B, \
```

I read that this was a normal behavior and that it should not compile.
However, how is this possible to compile on IAR?

(yes, i'm asking you to believe me without a reproducible working example because I won't provide my propretary code)

---

Edit: 
On [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/):

- x86-64 clang 10 ,: the code works only in c++! and in C produces a similar error:

  - `"type 'someEnum1_e*' in generic association compatible with previously specified type 'uint32_t *' (aka 'unsigned int *')"`
- ARM64 GCC 8.2, flag -std=c11: the code produces the error
- x64 GCC 9.3, flag -std=c11: the code produces the error
- AVR GCC 5.4, flag -std=c11: the code does not recognize _Generic, nor _Bool:

  - `"error: '_Generic' was not declared in this scope"`
- MSP430 GCC 6.2.1, flag -std=c11: the code works! (but not in C++)
- and on my computer with IAR 8.20.2, flag -std=c11: the code works!

***1st bonus question: Could it be a compiler bug? What does the standard says?***

***2nd bonus question: Is there a way to avoid the error? (for all compilers)***

A short snippet to test my sayings

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef enum
{
    ENUM1_A,
    ENUM1_B,
}someEnum1_e;

#define TYPE_E1_ 0
#define TYPE_U32_ 1

#define  GET_TYPE_(data) _Generic((&data)+0, \
           uint32_t* : TYPE_U32_, \
           someEnum1_e* : TYPE_E1_, \
           default: TYPE_U32_ )

int main (void)
{
    uint32_t foo;
    someEnum1_e bar;
    switch(GET_TYPE_(foo)){default:break;};
    switch(GET_TYPE_(bar)){default:break;};
}
```

Comment: What "online compiler" are you using? What is the actual compiler used by it? Which version of it? What flags are you passing to the compiler? Does it handle the C11 standard (or later)?

Comment: are you saying that this should compile?

Comment: Actually I think it *shouldn't*. C, unlike C++, doesn't introduce enumerations as separate types. An enumeration is just a set of named compile-time constant `int` values.

Comment: It also shouldn't build as C++ code as C++ doesn't have `_Generic`.

Comment: On another note, why do you use pointers as selection? Why can't you use plain `data` as the selector and use non-pointers types in the selection list?

Comment: pointer as selection is a little trick for adding raw array types. You can add it like this ```uint32_t(*)[] : TYPE_ARRAY_U32_, \```

Comment: This is related: [How to create type safe enums?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43043246/how-to-create-type-safe-enums). The accepted answer demonstrates a trick with a dummy union + compound literals in order to get a bit of type safety of sorts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to compile and run with all compiler in C11 (that accepts the _Generic keyword):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef enum
{
    ENUM1_A=0,
    ENUM1_B,
}someEnum1_e;


typedef union
{
    someEnum1_e value;
}someEnum1_e_t;


void print_uint32_t(uint32_t val)
{
    printf("uint32_t val = %u\n",val);
}

void print_someEnum1_e_t(someEnum1_e_t val)
{
    printf("someEnum1_e_t val = %u\n", val.value);
}

#define  PRINT_(data) _Generic((&data)+0, \
           uint32_t* : print_uint32_t((uint32_t)*((uint32_t*)&data)), \
           someEnum1_e_t* : print_someEnum1_e_t((someEnum1_e_t)*((someEnum1_e_t*)&data)), \
           default: printf("hello\n"))

int main (void)
{
    uint32_t       foo = 32;
    someEnum1_e_t  blah = {ENUM1_A};


    PRINT_(foo);
    PRINT_(blah);
}
```

For this solution to be working, I don't need the macro trick given by Lundin.

Comment: int32_t is not compatible with someEnum1_e_t, only uint32_t. On my system, at least.

Comment: Sorry, I skipped the `union` trick... `someEnum1_e_t` should be incompatible with both `int32_t` and `uint32_t`. So `_Generic` should indeed distinguish pointers to these. I don't known why anyone would downvote your answer.