# C function that allows two data types

Tags: c, types

Maybe its just a dumb question but I was wondering if there is a way to allow two data types in the same function parameter, sort of polimorphism that in the end does the same stuff, just to filter out some garbage input.

```
typedef enum
{

} type1_t;

typedef enum
{

} type2_t;

void myfunc(typex_t foo)
{

}
```

Comment: Short answer: No. C is a strongly typed language. Long answer: Sort of with `void*` and lots of voodoo, but that has the opposite effect of "filtering out garbage" as it lets anything in.

Comment: You can use a`union` maybe?

Comment: You can't use only one function. You can however use macros and [generic selection](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/generic) to call one of two functions depending on the type.

Comment: I would suggest using a tagged union.

Comment: If it's just enums, you could use an int.  But in any case you'll need a way of knowing what type was passed, won't you?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with this? Maybe this is an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) (I might be wrong). And what would you do with `foo` in `myfunc`? [Edit] and show expand your example.

Comment: Would your purpose be satisfied with either one type or the other, or do both need to be passed (therefore accessible from)  the same parameter?  i.e. if either/or use a `union`, if both, use a `struct`

Comment: Main problem here isn't the enum type actually, but to pass on an _enumeration constant_, since those always have type `int`. You can use some tricks from here: [How to create type safe enums?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43043246/how-to-create-type-safe-enums).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may consider a different approach, involving one of C11 features.

A [generic selection](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/generic)

> Provides a way to choose one of several expressions at compile time, based on a type of a controlling expression.

You'll end up with some code duplication, but also a common "interface".

```
#include <stdio.h>

void myfunc_int(int x){
    printf("int: %d\n", x);
}
void myfunc_float(float y){
    printf("float: %f\n", y);
}

#define myfunc(X) _Generic((X),     \
    int : myfunc_int,               \
    float : myfunc_float            \
) (X)

int main(void)
{
    myfunc(3.14f);

    myfunc(42);

//    myfunc(1.0);
//           ^ "error: '_Generic' selector of type 'double'
//                    is not compatible with any association"
}
```

Testable [here](https://godbolt.org/z/GPb6fb).

Comment: although it seems to work the code duplication is a big price to pay for such thing

Answer (score 4):

#### Tagged Union

You could use a union:

```
typedef union
{
    type1_t t1;
    type2_t t2;
} UnionType;
```

You need to somehow know if `t1` or `t2` is active. For this you can pass an additional enumeration value (A distinct value for each type you want to allow):

```
enum types
{
    TYPE1,
    TYPE2
};
```

Combine it to a struct, and there you have your `typex_t`:

```
typedef struct
{
    enum types type; // this is also called a type tag
    UnionType content;
} typex_t;
```

Or more compact (nonstandard)

```
typedef struct
{
    enum { TYPE1, TYPE2 } type;
    union { type1_t t1; type2_t t2; } content;
} typex_t;
```

This whole `struct union` construct is also called a tagged union.

Comment: In modern C you can do anonymous `union { type1_t t1; type2_t t2; };`. But then in modern C you'd probably use `_Generic` instead of them old enum tricks from back in the days.