# Can enums be considered unsafe?

Tags: c, enums

Since I know each element of an `enum` has its own integer value, I tried this:

```
enum Foo {
    Red = 0,
    Blue = 1
};

int main(void) {
    enum Foo bar = 2;
    return 0;
}
```

And it... works. I looked further and I think it has the same minimum and maximum limits as `int` (I started experiencing UB after `INT_MAX`). At that point, isn't an `enum` no better than a set of `#define`s? I could also very well be wrong here, though.

Comment: Almost anything is unsafe if you use it in a completely wrong way

Comment: In general, "safe" is a very relative term when it comes to C.

Comment: Yeah, I guess that's true. I generally use `enum class`es from C++ but since I was making a C-only program I tried out `enum`s and discovered this.

Comment: @mkrieger1 and @underscore_d your links are very helpful and I can see how `enum`s can still be important despite the issue, so thank you.

Comment: I't just as unsafe as this `char s[10]; s[13]='x';` Does that makes arrays unsafe?

Comment: @klutt yeah, that is true. I guess it all ultimately depends on the programmer not being stupid, in a way.

Comment: In C yes. Many other languages goes a long way to protect you, but C does not.

Comment: @klutt Yeah, I'm getting used to that more as I use C.

Comment: Some compilers have an option to automatically insert code to check the value.

Comment: I see. As @chqrlie mentioned in his answer, `clang`'s `-Weverything` alerts you when you assign a value to the `enum` that is not in the set of elements.

Comment: This is pretty much an exact duplicate: [How to create type safe enums?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43043246/how-to-create-type-safe-enums).

Comment: @Lundin: merely a subset: your question addresses a more general issue, ie: one that works for values not known at compile time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `enum` variable is an integer with a type large enough for the largest value defined in the `enum` definition, not necessarily `int` and potentially larger than `int` on some compilers. You can store int it any other value compatible with the storage type, no check is performed at run time.

If you increase your compiler's warning level, (eg: `gcc -Wall -Wextra` or `clang -Weverything`) you might get a warning about the value being different from all defined enumeration constants for the target `enum`.

For example **clang** produces these warnings when invoked with `-Weverything`:

```
test.c:7:20: warning: integer constant not in range of enumerated type 'enum Foo' [-Wassign-enum]
    enum Foo bar = 2;
                   ^
test.c:7:14: warning: unused variable 'bar' [-Wunused-variable]
    enum Foo bar = 2;
```

Comment: I tried `-Wall -Wextra` in `gcc` and `clang`. Unfortunately, it does not produce a warning.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1: indeed `-Wall -Wextra` does not suffice, but `clang -Weverything` complains.

Comment: Ah yes, I'm getting the warning now. Thanks.