# Implicit cast on function return in C and why Visual studio doesn't throw warning

Tags: c, types, enums, casting

I've compiled the following code:

```
typedef enum E_STATUS_A
{
    STATUS_A_FIRST = 0,
    STATUS_A_SECOND
}E_STATUS_A;

typedef enum E_STATUS_B
{
    STATUS_B_FIRST = 0,
    STATUS_B_SECOND = 15
}E_STATUS_B;

E_STATUS_B bar()
{
    E_STATUS_B val = STATUS_B_SECOND;
    return val;
}

E_STATUS_A foo()
{
    int val = 0;
    val = bar();
    return val;
}

int main()
{
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

After return from function `bar()` then `val` value is `15` and not `STATUS_B_SECOND`.

I got several questions:

1. I assume I receive back from `bar` the `enum` `STATUS_B_SECOND` and `val` gets the value `15` because of an implicit cast from `E_STATUS_B` to `int`, correct? If so why is it happening, and why my visual studio (2019) compiler is not notifying me on that?
2. If I change the `foo` code to:

```
E_STATUS_A foo()
{
    E_STATUS_A val = 0;
    val = bar();
    return val;
}
```

Then still, I get back from `bar` an `enum` of `STATUS_B_SECOND` however `val` itself is `15`, is it because of an implicit cast from `STATUS_B_SECOND` to `int`? If so, I guess it doesn't matter what's the definition of `val` in `foo`, as if there won't be exact fit from the return `bar` value type to the `val` type, it will always be casted as `int` (or some other primitive type that is closed to the returned value from `bar`)?

3. If I keep in the function `foo` `val` type as `E_STATUS_A` and I change the `E_STATUS_B` `enum` to

```
typedef enum E_STATUS_B
{
    STATUS_B_FIRST = 0,
    STATUS_B_SECOND
}E_STATUS_B;
```

And run the same code, I get `STATUS_B_SECOND` returned from `foo` however `val` itself is now of type `E_STATUS_A` and its value is `STATUS_A_SECOND`. This kind of confuses me, as from my previous code, when `STATUS_B_SECOND = 15` I got just `15` as a returned value, and now I get implicit cast for `E_STATUS_A` type. Is that correct? If so, how is the implicit cast chooses which type to cast, and why didn't just cast to `int`, and moreover, why visual studio didn't raise me a warning?...

Comment: `enum` in C isn't really all that robust and is really just an alias for an integer type plus a set of potentially automatically assigned values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some misconceptions:

- There is no such thing as an "implicit cast". There are implicit conversions, or explicit conversions. An explicit conversion can be done by the programmer by using the `()` cast operator, meaning that a cast is always explicit and always done by the programmer.
- Enums in general are not type safe. They consist of an *enumerated type* which is the type of the variable. It is guaranteed to be able to hold all the values of the enum and to be an integer type, but its size and signedness are not well-defined.
- The contents of an enum, such as for example `STATUS_A_FIRST` are *enumeration constants*. These are guaranteed to be of type `int` which is signed. Therefore, implicit conversions without compiler warnings between enumerated type and `int` are necessary for enums to function at all.

This inconsistency between the type of an enumerated type and the type `int` of its enumerated constants is a known design flaw in the C language. Basically C throws type safety out the window in favour for allowing compilers to pick smaller sized integer types than `int` for enumerated types, where it is possible.

Then in addition, you can generally implicitly convert between *all* integer types in C, including enumerated types. The compiler may or may not give a diagnostic when you do. Some of those conversions are not well-defined, such as when doing from certain unsigned to signed types.

---

> 1. I assume I receive back from bar the enum STATUS_B_SECOND and val gets the value 15 because of an implicit cast from E_STATUS_B to int, correct? If so why is it happening, and why my visual studio (2019) compiler is not notifying me on that?

For the reasons explained above, there are generally no compiler diagnostics when doing conversions between enums and `int`.

> 2. /--/ is it because of an implicit cast from STATUS_B_SECOND to int?

Yes, enum values are treated like integers in most cases. You might get a slight bit of improved type safety if you pass values through pointers, because pointer-to-type has stricter type safety rules than plain integer variables.

> If so, I guess it doesn't matter what's the definition of val in foo, as if there won't be exact fit from the return bar value type to the val type, it will always be casted as int

Note that enumerated types can store other values than those listed as the valid enumeration constants for that type. They are essentially just a glorified `int` with not much extra in the way of type safety.

> 3. /--/ and now I get implicit cast for E_STATUS_A type

No you don't. Enumeration constants are auto-incremented if you don't initialize them explicitly. So both `STATUS_A_SECOND` and `STATUS_B_SECOND` got value 1 in this example.

---

You might be interested in [How to create type safe enums?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43043246/how-to-create-type-safe-enums), though it's using somewhat advanced macro tricks and probably isn't very beginner-friendly reading.