# Compiler Warn on enum

Tags: c, gcc, enums

Is there a way to get the compiler to warn if an integer is outside the 'range' of an `enum` ? For example, something like this:

```
enum Brothers {Snee, Snoo, Snum};

int main(void) {

  enum Brothers k;
  k = Snee;
  k = 9; // compiler warning for an int outside [0,2] ?

}
```

Comment: each compiler has different options. which compiler are you using?

Comment: @phuclv updated question tags.

Comment: Duplicate: [How to create type safe enums?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43043246/how-to-create-type-safe-enums)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not for gcc as of version 10.2.  There's a related [open enhancement request from 2002](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=7654) but developers haven't seemed interested in implementing it.

clang will warn about this if given the `-Wassign-enum` option: https://godbolt.org/z/zv8an5

Comment: thanks, I think the 20th year will be the charm for implementing it :)

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find an option on GCC matching exactly what you want. There *are* some enum-related compiler flags for GCC that will make enums slightly more behaved. For example, `-Wenum-compare` will give a warning when comparing enums of different types for equality:

```
enum fruit {                                                                                                            
    APPLE,                                                                                                              
    BANANA                                                                                                              
};                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                      
enum colors {                                                                                                           
    RED,                                                                                                                
    BLUE                                                                                                                
};                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
if (APPLE == RED) { // -Wenum-compare gives compiler warning here.
    ...
}
```

The option you're looking for does seem to exist on [clang](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html#wassign-enum) though as `-Wassign-enum`.