# Limit an argument of a function to an enum type only

Tags: c, enums

I have an enum `day_t` which contains the days of the week.

```
typedef enum
{
    monday = 1,
    tuesday,
    wednesday,
    thursday,
    friday,
    saturday,
    sunday
} day_t;
```

I'd like to restrict the argument of a function `setDay(someType Day)` with the enum definitions (friendly names) **only**. Is it possible using an enum or something else?

For example I'd like to type in code the argument like this, with intellisense allowing me to see the other friendly names:

```
setDay(day.wednesday);
```

Thanks.

Comment: That's not a feature of C. For the code-writing autocomplete question, you could fake it with a struct where the elements have the same names as their enum values, but that's not a good solution. You may want to consider C++ and it's `enum class` if this is important. As for restricting the argument values, that's just something you have to check in the function itself.

Comment: The C standard does not provide features for this. Partly for historical reasons of how C developed, `enum` types are largely integer types and may be used interchangeably with other integer types. Separation between them is weak. Specific compilers might provide some additional features to warn you in a few cases.

Comment: `day.wednesday` isn't valid C so you can't do that. You might have to use a struct wrapper etc to get code completion in some IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to do this by using the tricks from [How to create type safe enums?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43043246/how-to-create-type-safe-enums) Taking the trick of type safe assignment described in the accepted answer:

```
typedef union
{
  day_t monday;
  day_t tuesday;
  day_t wednesday;
  day_t thursday;
  day_t friday;
  day_t saturday;
  day_t sunday;
} typesafe_day_t;

#define day_assign(var, val) _Generic((var), day_t: (var) = (typesafe_day_t){ .val = val }.val)
```

Then given some function `void set_day (day_t day)`, we can design a safe version using a wrapper macro:

```
#define set_day_s(day) set_day( day_assign((day_t){0},day) )
```

This makes a temporary copy of the passed argument and runs that through the type safety macro, blocking everything that isn't one of the mentioned enum constants.

Full example:

```
typedef enum
{
  monday = 1,
  tuesday,
  wednesday,
  thursday,
  friday,
  saturday,
  sunday
} day_t;

typedef union
{
  day_t monday;
  day_t tuesday;
  day_t wednesday;
  day_t thursday;
  day_t friday;
  day_t saturday;
  day_t sunday;
} typesafe_day_t;

#define day_assign(var, val) _Generic((var), day_t: (var) = (typesafe_day_t){ .val = val }.val)

void set_day (day_t day){ /* ... */ }
#define set_day_s(day) set_day( day_assign((day_t){0},day) )

int main (void)
{
  set_day_s(monday); //  OK

  day_t d=monday;
//  set_day_s(d);      // compiler error
//  set_day_s(1);      // compiler error
}
```