# How to get a warning when assigning integer to enum?

Tags: c, gcc, enums, clang, warnings

Is there a way to get Clang or GCC to warn when assigning a plain integer to a variable of enum type? This question refers to C, not C++.

Example:

```c
typedef enum foo_e { A=1, B=2 } foo_t;

foo_t fun() {
    foo_t x = A; // this is fine
    foo_t y = 2; // should trigger a warning
    int z = B;   // this is fine
    return 1;    // should trigger a warning, as the return type is foo_t
}
```

The "classic" Intel compiler issues a warning for these cases: warning #188, "enumerated type mixed with another type". This revealed several real bugs in our code. However, this being an open-source project run by volunteers, we do not have the possibility to test with this non-free compiler on a regular basis, and cannot integrate it into CI pipeline. Having seen the value of these checks, I am wondering if there is a way to get them with Clang or GCC.

Comment: That's not invalid. Enumerations and enumeration constants are really basically just plain integers. Actually it's quite common to use enumerations as bitwise flags, and use bitwise OR (`|`) to construct masks or bitsets, and then assign to a variable of the enumeration type.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude No, it's not invalid. That does not mean that getting a diagnostic for this is not useful.

Comment: @Szabolcs "enumerated type mixed with another type" looks like a C++ compiler warning.  In C, `foo_t` is not a new type.  "should trigger a warning" is incorrect for C.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: So there is a solution. Write that portion of the code so it can be compiled as C/C++. Compile as C++ to check for warnings. Compile as C for actual use in the program.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Interesting approach.

Answer (score 2):

Checking [the GCC warning documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-12.1.0/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options) shows no options that would do as you request.

There are options for missing enumeration values in `switch` statements (`-Wswitch` and `-Wswitch-enum`), comparisons between values of different enumeration types (`-Wenum-compare`), and conversions between different enumeration types (`-Wenum-conversion`).

Likely the compiler developers have felt that warnings about assigning `int` values to an lvalue of enumeration type will not be useful because it will warn about ordinary desired assignments such as `i = i+1` in:

```
for (enum weather i = sunny; i <= rain; i = i+1)
    …
```

In that, `i+1` is an `int` because `1` is an `int` and the operands of `+` are converted to a common type, and then this `int` is assigned to the `enum weather` `i`.

There are some [kludges to use enumerations with some type safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43043246/how-to-create-type-safe-enums).