# Can a C typedef enum take a value greater than the number of elements in the enum?

Tags: c, enums

I'm reviewing a lot of code that looks like this

```c
typedef enum {
    OPTION1
    OPTION2
} option_t

...

void a_function(option_t option){
    if(option == OPTION1){
        ...
    } else if(option == OPTION2){
        ...
    } else {
        // report an error!
        // can we ever get here?
    }
}
```

My question is, is the `else` clause that reports the error needed? It seems to me, that as `option` is of type `option_t`, an enum that only has 2 possibilities, it should not be possible for `option` to have any value except `OPTION1` and `OPTION2`, so it should be impossible for the `else` clause to ever be executed.

Comment: What would prevent a caller from passing `-1` or `4711` to your function?

Comment: @Gerhardh idk the compiler? Feels like `option` being an `option_t` instead of `int` should prevent that?

Comment: An `enum` basically simply defines names for constant values. It does not specify a specific integer type (signed or unsigned, short or long, ...) for them or put some limits in place.

Comment: Re “Can a C typedef enum take a value greater than the number of elements in the enum?”: That is not the question you want to ask; `enum foo { a = 12 }` has a value greater than the number of its named members.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Enums do not have much in the way of type safety and are generally broken by design type-wise (as of today's date, upcoming C23 will change many C language defects). In your example `OPTION1` is of type `int` and `option_t` is of some integer type large enough to fit all values in the enumeration list, not necessarily `int`.

> My question is, is the else clause that reports the error needed?

It is what's known as "defensive programming". In theory the enum should not have any other values. In practice, nothing is stopping you from assigning any integer value to it. Or in case of memory corruption bugs, nothing is stopping the bug from changing it to another value either.

So it depends on your requirements. For commerical/hobbyist/PC requirements, the `else` is probably not required. For safety-related, mission-critical or similar software (MISRA C compliance for example), the `else` is required and good practice.

Related post: [How to create type safe enums?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43043246/how-to-create-type-safe-enums)

Comment: I use unums instead if #define for one reason. Debuggers display names of the enums making debugging easier

Answer (score 4):

The C standard is not explicit about this, but each enumerated type is actually some regular integer type. Although C 2018 6.12.5 16 says “… Each distinct enumeration constitutes a different *enumerated type*”, 6.7.2.2 4 says “Each enumerated type shall be compatible with `char`, a signed integer type, or an unsigned integer type. The choice of type is implementation-defined, but shall be capable of representing the values of all the members of the enumeration…”

Neither of those is clear about what values can be represented in the enumerated type or whether the behavior is defined for values not among the named values of the enumeration—saying two types are compatible is not an assertion that all the values of one type are representable by the other type.